# <?xml ?> tag not working so wired

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am creating rss feed xml with PHP but the wired thing is when I add 
`<?xml ?>` at the start my PHP is not working - no error noting, and it's only on server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

any one knows what's wrong

Comment: Please add a short snippet of the code that is not working. are you trying to do something like `<?xml $foo = 'bar'; echo $foo; ?>`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "my PHP is not working"?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: thank you guys it was <? ?> php confusion, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the php file confuses the `<?` and `?>` of your xml tag with it's php tag. XML tags such as yours `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` can not be included in PHP for that specific reason.

Yes, it is considered to be a dumb situation that could easily be fixed by the PHP developers, though currently it's not an option in a php file.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't confirm this. A simple test script does _not_ show the issue you describe here. Could you please elaborate or add a short snippet demonstrating your case? Thanks!

Comment: It is a configuration option (`short_open_tag`), one that is disabled by default in current PHP versions. It is here for backwards compatibility. It can not be on the file level, because it needs to be defined before parsing the source.

Answer (score 1):

First, You can use

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

And second, you write xml header as string:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>
```